# Flutter/Dart HMAC-SHA1 encoding, and then request web api with header

Tags: flutter, dart, hmacsha1

I want to get a web API.
The web request using HMAC-SHA1 encoding.Just like below:
[image]

Following is my code:

```
getData(){
  String APPID = "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
  String APPKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  final String time = readTimestamp(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  final signDate = "x-date: $time";
  var key = utf8.encode(APPKey);
  var hmacSha1 = new Hmac(sha1, key);
  var hmac = hmacSha1.convert(utf8.encode(signDate));
  var base64HmacString = Base64Encoder().convert(hmac.bytes);

  var bytes = utf8.encode(""""hmac username=$APPID, algorithm="hmac-sha1", headers="x-date", signature=$base64HmacString""");
  var digest = hmacSha1.convert(bytes);
  visitAPI(time, '$digest');
}

String readTimestamp(int timestamp){
  var format = new DateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var time = format.format(DateTime.now().toUtc()) + " GMT";

  print(time.toString());
  return time.toString();
}

Future<void> visitAPI(String xdate, String authorization) async {
  final url = "https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/Bus/RealTimeByFrequency/Streaming/City/Hsinchu?\$top=30&\$format=JSON";
  final response = await http.get(url,
      headers: {"x-date": xdate, "Authorization": authorization});
  final jsonSt = json.decode(response.body);
  print(response.body);
}
```

I have tried many time but I still got the message:"HMAC signature cannot be verified". Is there any problem on my code? Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `authorization` value in testing api tool like postman?

Comment: I am the first time to heard postman, I'll try to use that tonight and test my authorization value.

Comment: No problem.....

Comment: I tried the postman last night. It request successed. so I think the problem comes from HMAC-sha1 encoding.

Comment: tried use the generated `xdate` and `authorization` value in postman. Is it requested successfully?

Comment: I solved the problem, It's like you said, the problem come from authorization value. After I recheck my Authorization value, I find something wrong(the " character). SO THANK YOU John Joe.

Comment: you're welcome :)